# How to let the user choose the output directory in PHP

Tags: php, directory

I am working on a code that converts a CSV file into a LDIF file. Now I got new requirements for the front-end. There should be the option to choose the directory/folder it gets placed in, but I don't have any idea on how to do it.

This is what I have right now:

```
    $fp = fopen($file,'w');
    foreach ($csvData as $entry){
        $dn = 'dn: uid='.$entry['uid'].',ou=';

        if($entry['Mitarbeiter '] == 'ja') {
            $dn .= 'Mitarbeiter';
        } else{
            $dn .= 'Extern';
        }

        $dn .= ',dc=utilution'."\n";

        fwrite($fp, $dn);

        foreach($entry as $key => $value){
            if($key == 'Mitarbeiter '||$value == ''){
                continue;
            }
            fwrite ($fp,$key.': '.$value."\n");

        }
        fwrite($fp,"\n");
    }
    fclose($fp);
```

This is the code I've used so far and I thought that there is the option to change the fwrite to a variable which could be changed by an directory option through the HTML.

Is there an element, such as a file-upload button, that makes it possible to select a directory?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not safe to let people add / replace files anywhere they want in your server.  An attacker can do bad things with this!  Your design should restrict them to choosing from some safe set of folders.  The folder choice must be enforced by the server code, do not trust the client to send valid data! Also enforce the file name extension on the server side so they can't pick foo.php and then run it.

Comment: For choosing the folder tree that is safe, like some "documents" folder that you created, you could have a filebrowse.php page that is called using AJAX to update the client side user interface,  It could start at the root of "documents" then the PHP code scans for files and sub-folders to return them as JSON.

Comment: @DaveS It's not for extern users, just for intern communication.

Comment: You could just set up an Amazon S3 shared bucket and use Cloudberry.